# sum of a positive series

Tags: arithmetic

For sufficiently large $m$, I want to calculate the following series.

> $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{3m}\sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{l=0}^m \min(i,j+k+l)$

Except considering all case by case, is there any clever trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{3m}\sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{l=0}^m \min(i,j+k+l)
&=& \sum_{j,k,l=0}^m \left[\sum_{i=0}^{j+k+l} i 
+ \sum_{i=j+k+l+1}^{3m}(j+k+l) \right]\\
&=& \sum_{j,k,l=0}^m \bigg[ \frac{1}{2}(j+k+l)(j+k+l+1) \\
&&+ (j+k+l)(3m-j-k-l)\bigg] 
\end{eqnarray*}

The sum can now be found using only 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^n 1 &=& n \\
\sum_{k=0}^n k &=& \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 &=& \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @user46185: Glad to help.